# How to configure Database with custom Datasource in MUlesoft

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-esb

I have a requirement that to configure the database connector using my custom-defined Datasource(Spring based). When configuring my data-source to DB Connector with my custom bean, I am getting an error that cannot set javax.sql.Datasource to org.mule.extension.db.internal.domain.data source.DataSourceConnetionSettings.dataSourceRef. When I didn't configure my DB connector and referred to the data source using java invoke, able to get the Datasource object. How can I pass this Datasource this my database connector in runtime?

Referred to the below but didn't help.

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Spring-based-datasources

Can someone help me with the last point in the below knowledgebase?

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-configure-connector-with-dynamic-parameters

```
<db:config name="Database_Config">

<db:data-source-connection dataSourceRef="myDbConnetor" />

</db:config>
```

My beans.xml as like below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.datasource.*" />
<bean id="myDbConnetor" class="com.test.datasource.MyCustomDataSource"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Please add the class com.test.datasource.MyCustomDataSource to the question. Also what are the versions of Mule, Database connector, Spring Module, Spring version? Please add all the information to the question.

Comment: Additionally to my previous requests of information, kinldy add more of the Mule configuration to show how the Spring context is being imported.
The question about the dynamic configuration is not clear, there is not enough context to understand it.